# Recyclerview cut off bottom of layout above it

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

[image]

Beneath the horizontal rule there should be a title saying Trailers
It's been cut off.  I've no idea why.

Here's the complete page xml

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <!-- should include the movie details -->
            <include layout="@layout/primary_detail_info"/>

            <ProgressBar
                android:layout_width="42dp"
                android:layout_height="42dp"
                android:id="@+id/pb_loading_bar"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:visibility="invisible"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerview_movie_trailers"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:paddingBottom="0dp"
                />
            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerview_movie_reviews"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"

                />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</FrameLayout>
```

Here's the included primary_detail_info.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    tools:context="uk.co.pottertour.popularmovieswithdb.DetailActivity">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                android:paddingStart="16dp"

                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                tools:text="Chappie" />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="185dp"
                android:layout_height="270dp"
                android:id="@+id/iv_detail_poster_thumbnail"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="41dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_title"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/movie_poster"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tv_release_date"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/iv_detail_poster_thumbnail"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_title"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                tools:text="Release date"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tv_vote_average"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/iv_detail_poster_thumbnail"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_release_date"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:padding="8dp"
                tools:text="8.1/10"/>

            <ToggleButton
                android:id="@+id/button_favourite"
                android:onClick="onclick_favourite_button"
                android:background="@drawable/favourite_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-smallcaps"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:textOn="Mark as\nfavourite"
                android:textOff="Mark as\nfavourite"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/iv_detail_poster_thumbnail"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_vote_average"
                android:checked="false"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tv_overview"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/iv_detail_poster_thumbnail"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                tools:text="Synopsis Blah blah blah"/>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:paddingBottom="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_overview"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:id="@+id/black_rule"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tv_trailers_label"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/black_rule"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:text="Trailers:"/>

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    </ScrollView>
</layout>
```

All the heights are set to wrap_content so really don't know, google isn't helping with these search terms, love some thought.

Comment: So which part is displaying "Trailer 1", as seen in your screenshot?

Comment: There's the hortizontal black line, and then the very top of T & i & l.  It's cut off the bottom of 'Trailers:'.  why?  How to fix?

Comment: Can't reproduce. Can you make a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please?

Comment: I've run it on my device, it appears to work.  Putting it down as an Emulator glitch.  Thanks for your attention kalabalik